# How to investigate if opencl is possible for an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, opencl

I have a heavy-duty algorithm in C# that takes two large `Bitmap`s of about 10000x5000 and performs photo and ray collision operations on a 3D model to map photos on the 3D model.

I would like to know if it is possible to convert such an algorithm to OpenCL to optimize parallel operations during the algorithm. But before asking you to go into the details of the algorithm, I would like to know how I can investigate if my algorithm is convertible to OpenCL.

I am not experienced in OpenCL and I would like to know if it is worth it to get into it and learn how it works. Are there things I have to look for that will definitely not work on the graphics card? (for-loops, recursion)

Update:

My algorithm goes something like:

```
foreach photo
    split the photo in 64x64 blocks
    foreach block
        cast a ray from the camera to the 3D model
        foreach triangle in 3D model
            perform raycheck
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, opencl is very possible for this type of work. ray casting is a place where gpu hardware can shine.

One way to divide this up:

```
foreach photo - work done by host application. (openmp?)
foreach block - use one opencl work group per block
foreach triangle in 3D model - single work item
```

There are some other things to consider when you implement this algorithm.

1) are there always 64^2 rays to be cast per block?

2) what ratio of rays will 'hit' the image and/or the geometry? conditional branches will hurt performance on gpu hardware.

3) have you considered casting from the geometry perspective, rather than the image? ie foreach triangle, foreach vertex, cast ray from camera and detect position on screen. you might be able to interpolate the remaining points on the triangle as well as z-buffer the results to prevent redrawing of the pixels.

4) if you are only crunching graphics, does opengl/directx have what you need already?

Comment: Thanks for the tips! The hit chance of the rays is pretty high, because the geometry is based on the pictures. So only the pictures on the edge of the geometry will have lower hit rays.

Answer (score 1):

To your specific questions: for loops are fine (although not optimal); recursion is not possible on a GPU.

In general, an algorithm that would work well on a GPU needs to have a lot of independent data-parallel operations. A lot of bitmap operations fall in that category, on the other hand, ray-tracing may be challenging.

If you can modify your algorithm so that you have a lot (several thousand) of independent blocks at the highest level, then dependencies in the lower levels within the block should be ok.

I think that's all I can say about such a general topic.

Comment: I have found some examples of ray tracing from a point to sphere, but I can imagine that the same will be possible for a plane or triangle. The separation in correct blocks will probably a bit harder, because I don't know on what level to split my data.

Comment: I have added a piece of pseudo-code of the algorithm. Maybe this could specify your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do it in OpenCL I would take the intermediate step of translating it into a multithreaded C program.  You will already observe a massive speed increase from this step, and it is a lot easier.  Also to write a kernel in OpenCL you need to use OpenCL C which is very similiar to normal C - so the translation step from this intermediate step will be easier than going directly from C#

In the end to do the OpenCL version what you have to do is share the memory of the photo from the host with the GPU (in fact for images, it has special memory APIs just for images that are aware of pixel encoding somehow compatible with OpenGL) and then create a raycheck kernel, and then from the host queue up the raycheck kernel for each block/triangle.

There is a good introduction talk from ATI on OpenCL here

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecYIsu83c0I

Comment: I have installed the Cloo project that makes a good connection between C# and OpenCL. Multithreading is indeed a good idea, but some laptops take about 10 minutes to work it out.

Comment: I think this provides a C# wrapper of the Host APIs, but you still have to write the kernel in OpenCL C correct?